# Image not loading imdb api using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, imdb, imdbpy

I am trying to show images from imdb api image shall show in todo.poster , it works perfectly fine when i try to access it locally. but when i deploy my project on server, images does not load the first time , but if i open the same image in new tab once and then refresh my project url , image would show. I am pretty much frustrated trying to solve this issue

```
<div ng-repeat="todo in todos">
    <a href="#show/{{todo.title}}">
        <h2>{{todo.title}}</h2>
    </a>
    <br>
    <a href="#show/{{todo.title}}">
        <img ng-src="{{todo.poster}}" alt="Image Not Found">
    </a>
</div>
```

**issue :**

```
http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTk4ODk5MTMyNV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMDMyNTg0Ng##._V1_SX300.jpg
```

If if use inspect element of my browser i see this error
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: could you share the server link to get a better idea?

Comment: I have a `404 - Not Found` on the given url.

Comment: how did you get the image URL? Which image is supposed to be shown?